# Finding record of family name change in New York City from 1943 or 1944

Tags: surnames, new-york-city, records, 1940s

During WW II my family changed their name. We all lived in New York City, Manhattan, at the time. The name change was made prior to my parents' application for citizenship.

Where might I find a record of that name change?

Comment: Are you certain that the name change wasn't simply a part of the naturalization process? That's how my dad did it, although his was a bit later (early 1960s): there was a place on one (or more) of the forms where he stated that his name after naturalization would be such-and-such.